# svg path moving when zooming 500%

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an html:

```
<svg class="know-me-highlight" viewBox="0 0 452 57">
            <path class="light-acqua" d="M 57 0 L 452 0 C 452 31.48023223876953 426.480224609375 57 395 57 L 0 57 C 0 25.51976776123047 25.51976776123047 0 57 0 Z">
            </path>
        </svg>
```

and CSS

```
.know-me-highlight  {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: 23.54vw;
  height: 5.28vh;
  bottom: 4vh;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

everything it's pretty still on normal zoom but when I zoom form 300% to 500% the SVG moves to the bottom. I tried wrapping in 2 divs one position absolute and the second float, but nothing changed. the problem seems related to the SVG but I have no idea why it's doing this. Does anyone have an explanation of why it's happening?

This is how it looks like normally
The second image shows how it looks like when it's stretched
[image]

[image]

EDIT: This is the full div

```
<div class="know-me-content">
        <div id="know-me-title">
        <div id="know_me_better">
            <span>Know me better</span>
        </div>
        <svg class="know-me-highlight" width="100px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 452 57">
            <path class="light-acqua" d="M 57 0 L 452 0 C 452 31.48023223876953 426.480224609375 57 395 57 L 0 57 C 0 25.51976776123047 25.51976776123047 0 57 0 Z">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

and this is the relative css:

```
.know-me-content {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  left: 10vw;
  bottom: 41.2vh;
  width: 50vw;
  overflow: visible;
}

.light-acqua {
  fill: rgba(167, 219, 216, 1);
}

#know_me_better {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 28vw;
  height: 6.49vh;
  line-height: 9.26vh;
  margin-top: -1.85vh;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5.56vh;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: 101;
}

.know-me-highlight  {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: 23.54vw;
  height: 5.28vh;
  bottom: 4vh;
  right: 3vw;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example (including the text in HTML etc.)

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix to your problem would be using a `<text>` element inside the svg something like this:

```html
<div class="know-me-content">
        <svg class="know-me-highlight" viewBox="0 0 452 57">
            <path fill="rgba(167, 219, 216, 1)" class="light-acqua" d="M 57 0 L 452 0 C 452 31.48023223876953 426.480224609375 57 395 57 L 0 57 C 0 25.51976776123047 25.51976776123047 0 57 0 Z">
            </path>
          <text x="226" y="45" text-anchor="middle" font-size="55">Know me better</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

In this case the svg element has no width or height and takes all the disponible width, i.e. the width of the parent div.